# CPU Tensorflow cannot be imported

Tags: tensorflow, installation, cpu

I have installed CPU version of tensorflow by command:

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

The [official guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install#install-tensorflow) says to execute:

```
# Current stable release for CPU-only
pip install tensorflow
```

So I believe I do it right.
I get the following error when i import anything from tensorflow.

```
ImportError: Could not find 'nvcuda.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Typically it is installed in 'C:\Windows\System32'. If it is not present, ensure that you have a CUDA-capable GPU
 with the correct driver installed.
```

Sounds like it wants to work with GPU instead. I have tried reinstalling everything and also popular solution:

```
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1' # also '','0'
```

It does not change anything.
I work with:

- Python 3.6.1
- Windows 10
- Radeon graphic card - so no GPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I have some unnecessary files in  "AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\" connected with tensorflow. Deleting them fixed my problem.